# Probability of getting H from tossing a coin is $p$. We toss a coin $n$ times. What is probability that number of H will be odd.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Probability of getting H from tossing a coin is $p$. We toss a coin $n$ times. What is probability that number of H will be odd.

My work.

If we toss one time then it's just $p$. P(#2)=$p(1-p)$, (#$2$) - $2$ tosses

And so if n is even then

$P$(#n)$=p(1-p)^{n-1} + p^3(1-p)^{n-3} + \cdots p^{n-1}(1-p)$

If n is odd.

$P$(#n)$=p(1-p)^{n-1} + p^3(1-p)^{n-3} + \cdots p^{n}$

How combine this two and get some compact form?

I can see geometric progression pattern but can't make use of that.

Comment: Can you recognise some kind of geometric series?

Comment: Well hold on a moment. Why is there no binomial coefficient here? Do I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: You forgot the binomial coefficients. The number of heads follows a binomial distribution: $$P(\text{# heads }=k)=\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ok but still how compute sum?

Comment: Duplicate question does not answer my question? It starts with guess which seems pretty unintutive.

Comment: I just added an answer to that question which is more intuitive.